# Code organization with flask, sqlalchemy and migrate

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

Here is my code structure:

```
├── ingen
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── invoice.py
│   │   └── user.py
```

`__init__.py` has something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    ...
    ...
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    return app
```

Also, the models are in their respective files. For example, here is `models/user.py`:

```
from ingen import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)


    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}> {}'.format(self.id, self.username)
```

Now, when I run
`flask db migrate`

It doesn't create tables for `User` because the class hasn't been found/imported yet.

The migration detects the model if I add the `User` class creation code at the end of `__init__.py` instead.

However, I don't like that from a code organization perspective. How do I ensure that the class gets picked up to generate the migration when in a separate file?

Comment: I think you need to add `app` to the SQLAlchemy initializer.
`db = SQLAlchemy(app)`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy is only able to register your models if you import them. Where you import them is irrelevant, they just need to be imported so that they are seen. Unfortunately there is no way around that.

If you want them to be somewhat hidden you can import your models in the env.py file that is generated in the migrations folder, but honestly, I prefer an explicit import somewhere in the application with a comment indicating that the models are imported so that they are registered with SQLAlchemy, not because they are used in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a manage.py and handle the migration operations from there. On top of my head i used it on bigger projects from time to time and it would look something like this.

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app, db

app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS']) # Regarding your organisation.

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

In general searching google with terms flask manager.py should point out some direction to you!

Good luck .

Answer (score -1):

Try use db.create_all()

like this in file `__init__.py`

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
   # create and configure the app
   app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
   ...
   ...
   db.init_app(app)
   db.create_all()
   migrate.init_app(app, db)
   return app
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You can't use `create_all()` and Flask-Migrate together, you have to use one or the other.